# Cleaning system for deployment test

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, visual-c++, deployment

I have a Qt Quick 2 project and I want to test its deployment on a clean Windows XP machine. This machine has Qt 5.2 and Visual Studio 2010 Express installed (I'm using Qt 5.2 compiled for msvc2010). I'd like to know how to change the system in a way that, for the deployed executable, will seem like a clean system with no dependencies installed (no Qt and MSVC2010).

Regarding Qt, it seems that renaming `C:\Qt` will be sufficient. What about MSVC? I know that the Visual Studio 2010 installation creates a directory (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0`) and also adds new DLLs to `C:\Windows\System32`. Does it do anything else? Will renaming the folder in `C:\Program Files` and the DLLs in `C:\Windows\System32` be enough?

Comment: I'd appreciate an explanation on the downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way around it but to install a clean copy of XP SP3 into a virtual machine and try it there.

You need to worry not only about what MSVC installs, but also what *every other application* has installed. Many applications install the MSVC redistributable, for example. It is impossible to do such tests on anything but a clean system - this excludes the OEM applications as well. You need a retail copy of Windows XP. They are available and are not too expensive.